# How can I draw "perfect" squiggly lines in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to create a logo that for the two "o" characters uses a series of squiggly lines in the the shape of an "o".

Sketch:
[image]
I did this with Paint but I obviously want consistency with the squiggly lines and close to a circular layout.

Why squiggly lines? Well, it's to reinforce the word itself being "loose".

Does anyone have any ideas how to tackle making this or tutorials that do similar things to word art?

Comment: Just an idea: I think this would be simple for someone who understands [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), or maybe even [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have illustrator:

- create 1 squiggly line
- duplicate the squiggly line to create a field of squiggly lines
- create a letter 'o' using the Text tool
- convert the 'o' to a path using Text > Create Outlines
- position the 'o' path over your squiggly lines
- select all the squiggly lines and your 'o' path
- mask the squiggly lines by the 'o' path using Object > Clipping Mask > Make

Comment: Did you hit the Submit button too soon? Looks like part of your answer is missing.

Comment: yeah WTH.. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop you could draw three squiggly lines and then put a layer over it with a transparent circle over the lines.